# RP 4 connecting to Asus ZenScreen monitor issue

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, touchscreen, connectors, usb-c

I'm very new to RP and I recently bought a new RP 4 and wanted to use a portable touchscreen monitor with it, but I wanted something bigger than the 7-10" ones I saw. I went for this one after a recommendation of similar screens

[Asus ZenScreen](https://www.asus.com/uk/Monitors/MB16AC/)

The problem is it has only one usb-c port that functions as both power and video. It didn't seem to be getting enough from the micro HDMI to usb c connector so I got a [splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08DJ2K1PK?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share) that separates the two as inputs (micro HDMI to HDMI and usb-c power) which then goes into the screen. All I get is the screen powering on and off in a loop.

They do have Linux drivers but I can't seem to open these, but I've read of people creating their own.

Is there anything I can try to get this to work?

And what is the likely problem here, is it driver related? Or more a case of connection issues?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome. Unless the source for the drivers is available you're out of luck; they won't come pre-compiled  for the Pi.  A quick search online implies the screen needs > 2A, so there is no way you could power it from the Pi.  A quick glance at the product page for that splitter implies you are trying to use it **backward**.  Have you actually seen any reports of anyone using this screen successfully? I could not find any...

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus Zen Screen with a USB 3 port and a USB 2. The USB 2 is to provide additional power in case the USB 3 doesn't provide enough current.
That said, the Pi does not output video out the USB port, so you would need some intermediate interface between the Pi and the screen to get it to work.